# NetBSD 7.0.2 not honoring hostname setting when using DHCP

Tags: networking, configuration, hostname, netbsd

I've recently installed NetBSD 7.0.2, and I'm having trouble setting my hostname right.

I'm using DHCP, so I got `dhclient=YES` in my `/etc/rc.conf`.

Now, the documentation says, that there are several ways of setting the hostname.
The prefered one is to put the hostname into a file. So `/etc/myname` contains a single line with the fully qualified domain name, etc.

This didn't help so I also added `hostname=<my fqdn>` into `/etc/rc.conf`, but it still doesn't honor my hostname settings.

This didn't help either, so I ended up editing `/etc/defaults/rc.conf` and set the appropriate settings there.

At this point I've run out of ideas. It's still not honering my selection, instead selecting a hostname for me, which is the name of my router plus a number.

Comment: You should check http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?dhcpcd+8+NetBSD-current which has many relevant options.

Comment: Depending on  the setup of your DHCP server, your hostname can be negotiated with the server, and you might have to accept the server's choice.  A packet capture of the negotiation might show what's going on.  Beware however that (contrary to the popular belief) DHCP is an enormously complex protocol.

Comment: @SatoKatsura:  Your last remark made me smile.  It may seem a bit abnormal to someone with very basic network understanding since it isn't IP based, but it's really quite simple.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I suppose it depends on how you look at it. The basic exchange is indeed simple. It becomes really hairy when you get to the extensions (some 400 pages of description, IIRC).  The vast majority of the time when it doesn't work, guess where's the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dhclient(8) (which is deprecated on NetBSD 6 and later), you need to add a `send host-name` clause to your `/etc/dhclient.conf`  file.  It should include the hostname you wish to use.

eg:
 `send host-name "eyeore";`

Comment: I like your answer but it seems to be missing the better alternative to this deprecated configuration.  :)

Comment: The preferred alternative is dhcpcd(8).  I believe the release notes since NetBSD 6.0 has stated that dhcpcd(8) has replaced dhclient(8), and dhclient(8) will be removed at some future date.

Comment: dhcpcd(8) also sends the host name to the DHCP server by default.

Comment: I've since fixed it using the `supersede` keyword